# Exception occurs when I added @Transactional on Jaxrs Resource

Tags: hibernate, jpa, quarkus

In the Quarkus Resource, I tried to write a Java 8 Stream in the Response.

I created MessageBodyWriter for the Stream type.

```java
@Provider
public class StreamBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Stream> {

    @Context
    private Providers providers;

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
                               Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return Stream.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Stream stream, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
                        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) { return -1; }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Stream stream, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
                        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
                        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        Object obj = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
        Class<?> objType = obj.getClass();

        MessageBodyWriter writer = providers.getMessageBodyWriter(objType,
                null, annotations, mediaType);

        writer.writeTo(obj, objType, null, annotations,
                mediaType, httpHeaders, entityStream);

    }
}
```

The Stream need a jdbc cursor to make it work, and it requires a transaction support.

I am sure I have installed a postgres jdbc extensions, and the application starts without errors.

```java
@Transactional
    public Response getAllPosts(
            @QueryParam("q") String q,
            @QueryParam("offset") @DefaultValue("0") int offset,
            @QueryParam("size") @DefaultValue("10") int size

    ) {
        return ok(this.posts.findByKeyword(q, offset, size)).build();
    }
```

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class PostRepository implements PanacheRepositoryBase<Post, String> {

    public Stream<Post> findByKeyword(String q, int offset, int size) {
        if (q == null || q.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return this.streamAll(Sort.descending("createdAt"))
                    .skip(offset)
                    .limit(size);
        } else {
            return this.streamAll(Sort.descending("createdAt"))
                    .filter(p -> p.title.contains(q) || p.content.contains(q))
                    .skip(offset)
                    .limit(size);
        }
    }
```

```java
@Entity
public class Post implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    String id;
    String title;
    String content;
    LocalDateTime createdAt;
```

When I added the CDI @Transactional on the Resource, and get the following error at start stage.

```
[38;5;203m: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not advance using next()
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:381)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:587)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:508)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:252)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:153)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:363)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:156)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:238)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.ResteasyFilter$ResteasyResponseWrapper.sendError(ResteasyFilter.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:175)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.ResteasyFilter.doFilter(ResteasyFilter.java:28)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PathHandler.handleRequest(PathHandler.java:91)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$9$1$1.call(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:513)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler.handleRequest(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:65)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$1.handleRequest(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:92)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.CanonicalPathHandler.handleRequest(CanonicalPathHandler.java:49)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.deployment.devmode.UndertowHotReplacementSetup.handleHotDeploymentRequest(UndertowHotReplacementSetup.java:85)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.deployment.devmode.UndertowHotReplacementSetup$1$1.handleRequest(UndertowHotReplacementSetup.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.CleanableExecutor$CleaningRunnable.run(CleanableExecutor.java:224)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2011)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1535)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1395)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not advance using next()
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.convert(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.next(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:105)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.ScrollableResultsIterator.hasNext(ScrollableResultsIterator.java:33)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1811)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
        at com.example.StreamBodyWriter.writeTo(StreamBodyWriter.java:39)
        at com.example.StreamBodyWriter.writeTo(StreamBodyWriter.java:17)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:193)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:64)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:155)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.lambda$writeNomapResponse$2(ServerResponseWriter.java:156)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ContainerResponseContextImpl.filter(ContainerResponseContextImpl.java:405)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.executeFilters(ServerResponseWriter.java:232)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:97)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:70)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:578)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is closed
        at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.ResultSetWrapper$1.invoke(ResultSetWrapper.java:49)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.next(Unknown Source)
        at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.ResultSetWrapper.next(ResultSetWrapper.java:85)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.next(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:100)
        ... 79 more
```

Comment: And you have set the properties as described in the docs? https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource-guide

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I just cleaned my codes, and ran the application again, got the **updated** exceptions.  Strangely, If I remove all `@Transactional`, the result is returned, but I am not sure if it is based on the cursor to get the result. From the print log, it query all results.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430329/quartz-scheduler-produces-resultset-is-closed-exception

Answer (score 0):

When you use an entity method returing a `Stream`, you need to have the method processing the it inside a transaction.

In your code, this is not the case, as the Stream is processed by your `StreamBodyWriter` where the `collect()` method lies.

To fix the issue, you must process your stream inside your `getAllPosts` or inside your `findByKeyword` method. So get rid of the `StreamBodyWriter` and return a Collection from your rest endpoint.

Comment: I know this way is working, but how to make Stream work well in StreamBodyWriter?

Comment: You cannot, it needs to be part of a transaction, the transaction implementation on Quarkus is based on a CDI interceptor that will intercept method calls annotated with `@Transactional`. I don't think your `StreamBodyWriter` could be part of a transaction as it will be used outside your JAX-RS Resource (the one that defines the transacton) by resteasy.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem and solved it like this:

Briefly about the problem: I use 2 datasources. When using the transactional annotation, which makes an update in the second database with a stream from the first database (which must be automatically closed), a similar problem arises.

Source code before:

```
@Override
  @Transactional(transactionManager = "firstTransactionManager", readOnly = true)
  public Stream<Foo> findStreamOfFoos() {
    return fooRepos.findStreamOfApplicationViews();
  }

@Async
@Override
@Transactional(transactionManager = "secondTransactionManager")
public void automaticallyUpdate() {
Stream<Foo> fooStream = fooService.findStreamOfFoos();
    try (fooStream) {
        fooStream.parallel().forEach(foo -> {
            // some code here
        });
    }
}
```

Source code after:

```
@Override
@Transactional(transactionManager = "firstTransactionManager", readOnly = true)
public Stream<Foo> findStreamOfFoos() {
return fooRepos.findStreamOfApplicationViews();
}

@Async
@Override
@Transactional(transactionManager = "firstTransactionManager")
public void automaticallyUpdate() {
Stream<Foo> fooStream = fooService.findStreamOfFoos();
    try (fooStream) {
        doJob(fooStream);
    }
}

@Transactional(transactionManager = "secondTransactionManager")
private void doJob() {
    fooStream.parallel().forEach(foo -> {
            // some code here
        });
}
```